# How to properly trim the edge of an input range track in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svelte

I am trying to build a slider component that looks similar to this:
[image: Slider with 5 dots - normal]

But the slider thumb will not extend past the edge of the line for the desired effect.
[image: Slider with 5 dots - thumb wont reach edge]

So I add a little bit of extra width with `width: calc(80% + 30px);` where the 30px is the width of the thumb and gives me a half of a thumb-width of overhang to work with.
[image: Slider with 5 dots - extended edges]

But when I try to clip the visible track to size with `clip-path: polygon(15px -1000%, calc(100% - 15px) -1000%, calc(100% - 15px) 1000%, 15px 1000%);`, it also clips the thumb.
[image: Slider with 5 dots - clipped thumb]

Is there a way to clip the track properly without clipping the thumb?

This is my code (organized as a .svelte component).

```
<script>
    export let name;
    let value = 3;
</script>

<style>
    input[type=range] {
        appearance: none;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #b3b3b3;
        width: calc(80% + 30px);
        height: 2px;
        padding: 0;
        top: -22px;
        clip-path: polygon(15px -1000%, calc(100% - 15px) -1000%, calc(100% - 15px) 1000%, 15px 1000%);
        border: none;
    }
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        appearance: none;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: yellowgreen;
    }
    span {
        margin-left: calc(10% - 8px);
        margin-right: calc(10% - 8px);
        float: left;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        padding: 0;
        background: #b3b3b3;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .tick-container {
        height: 16px;
        padding: 0;
        justify-content: left;
    }
</style>

<h2>{name}</h2>

<div class="tick-container">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<input on:input={slider => value = slider.target.value} type="range" min="1" max="5" value={value}>
```

Comment: Can you add a REPL link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just draw the groove separately instead of trying to make it work like this.

Also:

- You can just `bind` the `value` of the input.
- It helps to have a container element which is used to dictate the overall size
- Flexbox in combination with `justify-content: space-between` can be used to easily space the ticks from end to end.
- I would try to avoid specific sizes and use percentages where possible to decrease dependencies.

A sketch of such a slider component:

```html
<script>
    export let value = 3;
</script>

<style>
    .slider {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    .track {
        margin: auto;
        width: calc(100% - 30px + 16px);
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    .ticks {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .tick {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background: #b3b3b3;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .groove {
        height: 2px;
        background: #b3b3b3;
        position: absolute;
        width: calc(100% - 16px);
        left: 8px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    input {
        position: absolute;
        appearance: none;
        background: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border: none;
    }
    input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        appearance: none;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: yellowgreen;
    }
</style>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="track">
        <div class="groove"></div>
        <div class="ticks">
            <span class="tick"></span>
            <span class="tick"></span>
            <span class="tick"></span>
            <span class="tick"></span>
            <span class="tick"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" bind:value> 
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/13b81531b13c48b384a6945bb089875e?version=3.48.0)

This could be further improved/extended:

- Export `min`/`max` and generate the ticks via `{#each}`
- Use custom properties for the colors/sizes of the ticks and the thumb
- Make compatible with other browsers (`::-webkit-slider-thumb` is non-standard)